# Why my pagination doesn't start at new line?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As you see the picture, The pagination comes right next to the content.
How can I start it at new line? I mean the bottom of content.

**HTML**

```
<% @communities.each do |community| %>  
    <%= render 'communities/community', :community => community %>
<% end %>

<div class='pagination-centered'>
    <%= paginate @communities, :window => 4, :outer_window => 5, :left => 2, :right => 2 %>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your communities container uses `float:left`.
you should use `clear:both` for pagination containger

Comment: which pagination gem you r using??